# Installation of Oracle 11g on remote server(Ubuntu) connected using ssh

Tags: ubuntu, oracle, oracle-11g

When I tried running installer of oracle using oracle user after remotely connected(using ssh), I am getting this error.

```
[oracle@htrtret database]$ ./runInstaller
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 120 MB.  Actual 1195 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.  Actual 4094 MB    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors
    >>> Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    Failed <<<<

Some requirement checks failed. You must fulfill these requirements before
continuing with the installation,at which time they will be rechecked.

Continue? (y/n) [n] y

Rechecking installer requirements....
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2010-10-26_07-29-52AM. Please wait ...Error in CreateOUIProcess(): 13
: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it with X forwarding:

```
ssh -X <hostname>
```

You'll need to be running an X server on the machine you're connecting from and ensure that "X11Forwarding yes" is set in sshd_config on the server.

Comment: I am connected to ssh using putty. so I enabled X11 forwarding and haven't set "X11 display location. Do you mean by "X11Forwarding yes" is set in sshd_config on the server? is setting ForwardX11 yes? I am on windows.What else do i need to make sure runInstaller work fine frm ssh window?

Answer (score 0):

Just installing the binaries, right? If you have an existing installation

1. Tar and gzip the ORACLE_HOME and scp it across
2. Unpack it in the location that you want the new ORACLE_HOME
3. `cd $ORACLE_HOME/clone/bin`
4. `perl clone.pl ORACLE_HOME=/my/oracle/home ORACLE_BASE=/my/oracle/base ORACLE_HOME_NAME=MyOraHome`

This is a headless technique for mass deployments.

Make sure you have all the prereqs. The base way to do this is add the [Oracle Yum server](http://public-yum.oracle.com/) and `yum install oracle-validated`.

Comment: I am running runInstaller as oracle user on my ssh window connnected to remote ubuntu server.

Comment: I am running runInstaller as oracle user on my ssh window connnected to remote ubuntu server.I tried enabling X11 forwarding to run the oracle installer.Please see my answer on this post , where I am getting errors with X11 forwarding.

Comment: You don't need X at all for a clone install.

Comment: Have you done xhost + on your local machine?

Comment: It doesn't look like this is a clone install.  What leads you to think it is?  Also, don't suggest to people they run `xhost +`, it's almost always a bad idea these days.

Comment: Yes I know it isn't - but a clone install is the right way to do this

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with writing some data from oracle on a non-writable directory(default tmp).So changed it using export TMP=$HOME/tmp.

I tried enabling X11 forwarding to run the oracle installer.Now I am getting this error:

Xlib: connect                                            ion to "localhost:10.0" refused by server
Xlib: PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authentication protocol attempted
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window                                              server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$000(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java                                            :53)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:142)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:1                                            31)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvi                                            ronment.java:68)
        at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:270)
        at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:318)
        at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:419)
        at oracle.ewt.popup.PopupFrame.(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.ewt.lwAWT.BufferedFrame.(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.(OiocOneClickInsta                                            ller.java:328)
        at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.(OiocOneClickIns                                            taller.java:168)

Answer (score 0):

To install using the graphical installer you need the following:

- X11 server installed on your workstation. For Windows you can use: [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/)
- ssh X11 forwarding enabled on the remote server. Check that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has the following option `X11Forwarding yes`
- xauth configured for oracle user, or connect directly as oracle user
- X11 forwarding enabled in PuTTY.

If you use sudo to connect to oracle user, then create /etc/profile.d/sudo-oracle.sh file with the following content:

```
function sudo {
        local u=oracle
        local SUDO_BIN=/usr/bin/sudo
        if [[ "x$1" == "xsu" && ( "x$2" == "x$u" || "x$3" == "x$u" ) ]]
        then
                echo X11 authentication from user $USER to user $u
                $SUDO_BIN -H -u $u xauth add $(xauth list|grep :$(echo ${DISPLAY: -4:2}))
        fi
        $SUDO_BIN $@
}
```

Then login to oracle account using:

```
sudo su - oracle
```