# Non GUI installer version for oracle 11g

Tags: linux, ubuntu, oracle

I am looking for a installer version which is entirely non GUI . since I have to install oracle 11g on a remote server(OS: Ubuntu). I am connected to remote server through ssh using putty.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a response file using the gui installer on a local server and then run the installer with the response file on the remote server.

Comment: You can also edit a supplied silent response file, though I'd recommend Erik's method, especially since you are running on an unsupported OS and will (probably) need to bypass pre-requisite checks.

Comment: Here's a useful link http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/em.920/a96697/rsp.htm.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use X Windows over SSH to install.  I've done it a half-dozen times with servers around the world.

Make sure XForwarding is enabled in your sshd_config file.  Connect to the server with an X client (I use a Mac, so I can run the built-in X11 client and connect with "ssh -X servername".)  I would expect you can do it with Putty but am unsure how.

Unpack the Oracle zips and execute *runInstaller* from the unzipped directory.  You will get the remote GUI in your X client.

Beware that it can be slow if running halfway around the world over the Internet but it will work if you are patient.

Answer (score 0):

Dupe of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/195283/installation-of-oracle-11g-on-remote-serverubuntu-connected-using-ssh/195314#195314) which I answered for you already.